# IdentityServer4 Not Redirecting to Mobile App Redirect URI when hosted

Tags: xamarin.forms, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am experiencing an issue where IdentityServer4 will not redirect to mobile app redirect URI (e.g. xamarinappname://callback) when it is hosted on a server. It is working fine when Identity Server is ran locally.

Is there anything I should be on the lookout for configuration-wise for this? Is IdentityServer4 viewing the mobile app redirect URI as invalid, but only when hosted?

Comment: Note: I am using `AddAppAuthRedirectUriValidator` and I am using the same dev DB instance for localhost and this hosted environment

Comment: @d_f The final redirect the app sees is to /authorize endpoint. At no point does a subsequent xamarinappname://callback come through to the app browser.

Comment: and what's in the logs or IS? does it redirect you to login screen before?

Comment: Just got ahold of the logs from the Azure Web App. Looks like it is failing to find the certificate used for signing. The certificate IS there so I'm not sure why this is failing only in a Azure Web App scenario. Just deployed to IIS on a VM and it works fine there (not the end state I want, though).

Comment: So the question is more about Azure. You have to update it, including the title and tags...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by title and tags, but I was able to resolve the issue by putting the certificate in the SSL certificate store and reading it from there. Reading from filesystem did not work, even though the certificate was present.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to change how I was loading my signing certificate. The Azure Web App instance refused to load the certificate from the file system (even though it was present in the location the code was looking for it).